# Copying man pages from tmux copy mode

Tags: tmux, man

I am in `xterm` on Pangolin, inside a `tmux` session, in `copy mode`. I am trying to copy the text of a `man` page but what I yank into the clipboard by using the simple `vi` bindings of spacebar/enter is text full full of whitespace which I can't just paste into `vim`.

- How can I view a `man` page as "plain text", perhaps even outside of the `man` program?
- Alternatively, how can I use the `tmux` copy mode to properly copy the text as it appears on the screen so that <kbd>CTRL+]</kbd> pasting it elsewhere will be faithful to the formatting I intended to reproduce?

EDIT: I should mention that the command `capture-pane`, followed by `save-buffer`, *works* to save an *entire* buffer to a file. I am looking for something less of an overkill: simple copy mode, select and yank, paste somewhere else; for example: inside `vim`.

Comment: Are you aware that you can pipe the output of `man` directly?  Is there a reason you need to go through `tmux`?

Comment: No, I am not aware of that. Please teach me how to get a simple txt file from a man page... that would be an answer I would immediately accept.

Comment: Try `man man > saved`.  It usually works for me.

Comment: Yes, it does. I can accept the answer. Ideally I would be able to format it too (e.g. specify a width in columns, not just the terminal $COLUMNS value it seems to pick up automatically...)

Comment: I'm sure there is a way to do that - maybe someone else can answer.  `man` itself is basically a convenience wrapper that looks up desired man pages, formats them using some form of `roff`, and typically caches the formatted output somewhere for faster future access.

Comment: I can paste text I copy from man pages using tmux copy mode to vim just fine. Is it possible you're not setting `:set paste` in vim before the paste?

Comment: @gokcehan: that was EXACTLY it! You solved it!! Please enter it as an answer and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so as I told in my comment, there's a `paste` option in vim which disables insert mode keybindings as well as other options such as automatic indentation so that you can paste some text in insert mode without deformation. you can turn it on using:

```
:set paste
```

after you paste you probably want to turn it off again using:

```
:set nopaste
```

there's still the issue that you can't scroll your man page in tmux copy mode therefore you can only copy a screen full of text at a time but still it may become convenient for some cases.

Answer (score 0):

Piping output of man through `col` helps a lot and it's probably better than using `copy mode`, I am still going to wait a bit for an answer using `tmux` though. Here's how I make do in the meantine:

```
COLUMNS=9999 man tmux | col -bx > /tmp/tmp
```